# Where to put custom made functions in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my models.py I have this class.

```
import time

class Ticket(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    booking_time = time.time()
    expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want the expired bool to turn to true if 1 hour has been passed since the `booking_time` but I don't have any idea where should I check for the same thing(I was thinking to make the function in `views.py` but views are only called when we go to a certain URL, in my case I want to check it every hour).

Comment: A better data model might be to just have an `expiry_time`; you can then get active tickets based on `Ticket.objects.filter(expiry_time__gte=now())`

Comment: Also, that `booking_time` field won't work. You're looking for `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`.

Comment: @AKX Oh...Thanks. I did the `DateTimeField` before but removed because I thought calculations using `time.time()` would be much easier. Also, I can't understand your first comment, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

If you want something like script running in your background in django, you can create for example script.py in your app folder. In that code you can even have

```py
def main()
    while True:
       ....
```

Then you have to go to wsgi.py (in your project folder) and import your script.
So it would be like

```py
import os
import threading

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'weather_raspi.settings')


t = threading.Thread(target=main, args=(args)) #here will you give the function as task and arguments into args
t.start() #this line starts the function
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This should work fine for you purposes
Hope you'll get it this time

Comment: Just make sure that something (e.g. a process manager) ensures the script is restarted if it dies unexpectedly...

Comment: I see, Thanks! Also, the script won't keep looping in the while loop and affect the functioning of django, right?

Comment: I tried to do this but when I try to connect over localhost:8000, the browser responds with the site can't be reached and as soon as I remove the function, everything starts working again.

Comment: That's kinda weird, because it works for me. Wait a minute

Comment: @ČervMoskomors Can, you please help me a bit to make it work?

Comment: So what's a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to change you model to use a expiration_time instead of expired boolean, then you can define a function checking the expiration_time vs now()

```py
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ...
    expiration_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def expired(self):
        return self.expiration_time > datetime.now()
```

or as a query:

```py
expired_tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(expiration_time__gt=Now())
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#now

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean, can you explain with a bit of code maybe?

Comment: Thanks for edit. Also, can you please explain what `expiration_time__gt=Now()` does?